# Use MID, LEN, and FIND functions to extract certain portions of a cells text?

Tags: excel, function

I have an Excel assignment and I'm stuck on the final portion. I'm asked to use MID, LEN and FIND in order to extract specific strings within cells. I have good understanding of how each one works individually; combining all three and getting them to work is the problem I'm having.

I need to separate the city from the rest of the address, which will then be displayed in a separate cell. I need to take the data from column B and only display the city in column G. This is what my worksheet and formula looks like:

Formula: **=MID(B3,FIND(",",B3)+1,15)**

[Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP4LQ.png)

[Worksheet with formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PmvH.png)

I have the city somewhat by itself. However, as you can see, there is still a space and the state is still showing. I'm not sure how to use LEN with MID and FIND in order to get rid of the state identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know how to find the city, and want to cut the rest of the text after it, you can use `Len` combined with `Find`:

`=MID(A1,FIND(",",B3)+1,LEN(B3)-FIND(",",B3)-3)`

`Len(B3)-Find(...)-3` will be the Number of Characters to return, after finding the `,`.  This, in your first example, will be 24-15-3=6. So it'll return the space, then "Milan"

Then, just wrap `Trim()` around all that to remove any leading and/or trailing space.

Just for fun, in case you ever have more than `NM` (or a two letter abbreviation), you can use this:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(B3," ",";",4),SEARCH(",",SUBSTITUTE(B3," ",";",4))+1,SEARCH(";",SUBSTITUTE(B3," ",";",4))-1-SEARCH(",",SUBSTITUTE(B3," ",";",4)))
```

So, if you have `1880 Atkins Rd, Milan New Mexico`, it'll still just return `Milan`.

Comment: So you're able to use the same function more than once? I did not know that. The book my instructor picked for the course is terrible and doesn't explain the problem solving methods nearly as well as it should. Thank you!

Comment: @McNasty49 - What do you mean "...use the same function more than once?"  ...You can use the same formula in a formula, as many times as you like! (Until you hit a character limit in the cell anyways).

Comment: I meant formula xD, I'm doing Excel and Java at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Ugh you beat me to it.

`=MID(B1,FIND(",",B1)+2,LEN(B1)-FIND(",",B1)-4)`

Use this and you don't need trim.

Find the comma, start 2 characters after it (ignore the comma and the space).

Then, get the length of the string - the starting position of the comma and the characters at the end.

Comment: Thank you as well!