# VBA Finding Numbers, Letters, and Characters in Cell and Replacing Content of Cell With Only Numbers/Letters

Tags: string, vba, excel

Having another problem.

I am creating another Excel tool at my facility and currently what I have pulls data from a purchase order tracking website and filters out superfluous data, leaving only the purchase order label itself, a single quotation mark, and an end bracket. I need to remove the quotation mark and ending bracket so I only have the PO itself, as I need this to inject into another site's URL. I have tried using wildcards with some code I wrote however the PO will get replaced with several asterisks, aka "wildcards," instead. I am probably overlooking something obvious, but I can't figure it out.

Example of data:

[image]

Code example:

```
Sub Filter_DockMaster_Data2()

Dim Main As Worksheet
    Set Main = Worksheets("Main")
Dim ISA_List As Worksheet
    Set ISA_List = Worksheets("ISA_List")
Dim ISA_Results As Worksheet
    Set ISA_Results = Worksheets("ISA_Results")
Dim ISA_Raw As Worksheet
    Set ISA_Raw = Worksheets("ISA_Raw")

Worksheets("ISA_Results").Select
Range("A1").Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        ActiveCell.replace What:="********"" ]", Replacement:="********", LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

Hopefully this makes sense.

Quick notes, the length of the PO will vary as time goes on, so I would like to make it dynamic if possible. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Encode for a URL

How about the function *intended* for making text URL-friendly?  :)

```
=ENCODEURL(A1)
```

For example, this:

```
1234ABCD']
```

...becomes encoded as:

```
1234ABCD%27%5D
```

...ready to insert in a query parameter (URL) string.  See the documentation including further examples at at the link below.

---

### Text Functions like `LEFT`

That said, there are several other ways to do this.

You said "replace" but it looks like you just need to cut off the last 2 characters?

This cuts the last 2 characters of the text in `A1`:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)
```

---

### `SUBSTITUTE` Function

If you *do* want to "replace" text in a cell, you can use `SUBSTITUTE`:

***Example:***

If cell `A1` contains:

```
1234ABCD']
```

...you could enter in another cell:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"]","")
```

...which would remove only the `]`.  You can also **nest** functions.  To remove both the `]` *and* the `'`, use this formula instead:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"]",""),"'","")
```

---

***The `SUBSTITUTE` function syntax:***

### **`SUBSTITUTE(` *`text, old_text, new_text, [instance_num]`* `)`**

The `SUBSTITUTE` function syntax has the following arguments:

- `Text` - *(Required)* The text or the reference to a cell containing text for which you want to substitute characters.
- `Old_text` - *(Required)* The text you want to replace.
- `New_text` - *(Required)* The text you want to replace `old_text` with.
- `Instance_num` - *(Optional)* Specifies which occurrence of `old_text` you want to replace with `new_text`. If you specify `instance_num`, only that instance of `old_text` is replaced. Otherwise, every occurrence of `old_text` in text is changed to `new_text`.

<sub>([**Source & More Info**](https://support.office.com/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332))</sub>

---

### More Information:

- Microsoft Support: [**`ENCODEURL` function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/article/encodeurl-function-07c7fb90-7c60-4bff-8687-fac50fe33d0e)
- Stack Overflow : [**Use `MID`, `LEN`, and `FIND` functions to extract certain cell portions?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42984530/8112776)
- Microsoft Support : [**`SUBSTITUTE` Function**](https://support.office.com/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)
- JayTray : [**The `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `MID` formulas in Excel**](http://blog.thejaytray.com/len-left-right-mid-formula/)
- Microsoft Support : [**Text functions** (reference)](https://support.office.com/rticle/text-functions-reference-cccd86ad-547d-4ea9-a065-7bb697c2a56e)

Comment: That is a ton of useful information, thank you. Honestly I was not aware there was even a function to automatically convert text into URL readable. I have only been in this role for a couple weeks now and let's just say my training wasn't the best. This was incredibly helpful though, so again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem shouldn't be about repairing the the data you've extracted from some source. It really should be about fixing the retrieval procedure so you do not get rogue characters.

With that said, this sub procedure should quickly remove any rogue characters from column A.

```
Option Explicit

Sub posOnly()

    Dim i As Long, str As String, rgx As Object

    Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    'pattern for A-Z (case sensitive) or 0-9 exactly 8 characters/digits in length
    rgx.Pattern = "[A-Z0-9]{8}"

    With Worksheets("ISA_Results")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            str = .Cells(i, "A").Value2
            If rgx.Test(str) Then
                str = rgx.Execute(str).Item(0)
                .Cells(i, "A") = str
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```